# Can I set the track ids after the video is playing?

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I'm trying to implement subtitles on a Chromecast Android app but I don't see a way to add the tracks after the media is already playing. Am I missing something or is that not possible? I'm pretty sure I've seen other apps doing it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add tracks after a media is loaded; you need to either add the tracks before loading the media or add and then reload the media

Comment: Thanks for the info. I know there are apps doing it somehow, is that just done through a custom receiver?

Comment: Let me make sure I understand the question; the title of your post is somewhat different from the post itself. What the current SDK can do is the following: when you load a media item (using the load commands on the sender side), you need to have set the tracks on the media. Then, at any point in time, you can set which one of those should be the active one (or turn the CC off). What you cannot do is to load a media with no tracks info and then as it is playing, "add" one or more tracks. So please let me know what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: I totally see that my title might be wrong. Sorry still learning the terms. What I want is to allow the user to look through a list of subtitles from a list and select the one that matches their video, it would be at that time that I would know where the subtitles are, etc, not before that. Ideally I would want them to do this once the video is playing, not before. It sounds like that isn't possible? So assuming that isn't possible, how are other apps doing this? are they just using the custom receiver? or did they implement their own subtitles parser at the receiver end?

Comment: Usually each media has a list of tracks already known as part of the catalog or some other means. if that is the case, you do add those tracks to your MediaInfo before loading the media and then while video is playing, user can see the list of tracks and select one or disable it. Try the first three videos in the CastVideos-android app; they have tracks.

Comment: In some cases, tracks are directly loaded by the recevier (MPL for example) since it is defined/embedded in the manifest, etc. In those cases, the receiver, loads the tracks and media and after loading them, will send a status update to the connected senders so they can learn about the presence of tracks and they can present the list of available tracks to the user again. Outside of these two, the current SDK/MPL do not support loading a track after the video is loaded

Comment: In my case I don't have the subtitles until the user chooses them but I think you've answered my question. Thanks.